# testing a web application

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsp, testing

I am a student and I have developed a web application based on JSP. Now my professor has suggested that i should do some tests like unit test etc for my web application.
Can anybody suggest what other test can I use to demonstrate the performance of my application.
And also any good resource from where I can study how to do unit testing, as I have never done any testing before.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it works if you didn't test it?

Comment: Wikipedia and Google are good places to start.  Using Search on the upper right corner of this page is a better place to start than by asking a question.  Seriously. **Searching** here is better than asking.

Comment: I have checked that the functionality I had wanted it to have are there and working properly, by testing it with some random test data, but I am not sure if that's the formal way of testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a popular framework for client-side unit tests (i.e. automating client input on a web page). The site also has a lot of introductory material.

For testing the server-side stuff the good, old JUnit will suffice - it's integrated in all major IDEs.

You should look into Kent Beck's [Test-driven Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530), although Test-Driven development is more than regular unit testing, this book will enlighten you (I bet) and you will write way better unit tests, too.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should do unit testing for individual backing beans, an behavioural testing with something like [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/)

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is "integration testing."

"Unit testing" is for proving the correct operation of individual components.

You can use SOAP UI to test SOAP-based web services.

You can automate testing of HTML user interfaces using Selenium UI.

Use JUnit for unit testing Java components, NUnit for .NET, etc.